# How to push from an often rebased git-svn repo

Tags: git, git-svn, push, rebase

I do all my daily work through git-svn, queuing up checkins and rebasing like a mad-man :)
the down side to this is I often have a couple days work queued up (tisk tisk i know) and it makes me a little nervous that its only in one place. If I was not using git-svn and rebasing all the time i would just push my changes to another computer and clone it if i do something stupid and loose data.

What is your advice on pushing often-rebased git repos?

Comment: What's wrong with a Plain Old Backup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have your own remote copy to stomp all over. Storing a bare repo in dropbox is one way to go. Push to that and when you've rebased, `push --force`

Comment: @Arthur: Don't use `--force` on a repo that other people pull from, it will break their clone. Only use it among your own copies.